# Identifying and counting distinct outputs in python from csv file

Tags: python

I am pulling data from a csv file and have it printing out three letter country codes from each row of data.  How do I make python identify the number of occurrences of each unique country code from the outputted data?  Here is what I have that is printing the country codes.

```
import csv

with open('2017CountryData.csv') as csvfile:

  readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
  for row in readCSV:
        countries = row[1]
        print(countries)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `Counter` class in the `collections` module.

Comment: Use a `Counter` [How to count the occurrences of a list item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-to-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item/5829377#5829377). Declare `count = Counter()` above the loop, then inside the loop increment it: `count[country) += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import csv

with open('2017CountryData.csv') as csvfile:
    countries = []
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if row[1] not in countries:
            countries.append(row[1])

print(Counter(countries))
```

Comment: Small point, you don't *need* to convert a `Counter` object to a regular `dict` object. A `Counter` *is* a dictionary, just with some modifications / additional methods specific to counting.

Comment: @jpp thanks for your point. I doubt OP might get confuse with output of `Counter` object, so thought about converting to a regular `dict`.